# R package devlopment: how to use a variable to save some state?

Tags: r, scope, package

### Minimal scenario

Suppose a package which needs to monitor its own usage. For example, the number of times a specific function of the package has been called since the package was loaded.

What is the best way to achieve this?

---

### First idea

I have tried to create a variable inside the `.onLoad()` function:

```
## R/zzz.R

.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  how_many_times <- 0
}
```

But this variable is not accessible after the package loading...

---

### Second idea

A variable inside some of the `.R` file. And the use of the scoping assignement operator `<<-`:

```
## R/somefile.R

#' @exports
how_many_times <- 0

#' @exports
count_me <- function() {
  how_many_times <<- how_many_times + 1
  how_many_times
}
```

But it does not work either! The first defined global `how_many_times` is not changed when I call the function `count_me` but it is another variable as a **closure** inside the function which is modified.

Comment: Second is an acceptable way to go, and is likely the easiest and most direct. You shouldn't need to remove it manually, as unloading the package should allow R to do garbage-collection naturally (namespace removal).